# Перенос платформенных файлов в отдельную папку

Tags: c#, build, tfs

У мне есть приложение, которое использует определенную платформу
Все файлы платформы находятся в корне приложения
Подскажите, где можно в настройках проекта, приложения или Build-сервера(для build-а используется TFS) указать, что платформенные файлы необходимо складывать в определенную папку, и, чтобы мои проекты видели эти файлы

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы больше конкретики по вопросу конечно. Но если данные файлы лежат где-то в доступном месте, то можно просто задачу копирования использовать: [Copy Files task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)